# Can I setup my laptop as a webserver without static IP?

Tags: linux, web-hosting, local-area-network

I want to use my laptop as a server and want to access it from a domain. I have installed PHP, MySQL and Apache on it.

I have read many blogs and they say I need to have an static IP for my laptop and need to forward my domain name to my laptop's static IP.

Is there any other way to do this? Any 3rd party service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to host a service on a dynamic IP address, you can use [DynDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service to associate your dynamic IP with a DNS name. When configured, you can access your service using the provided name which points to the current IP and gets updated continuously.

Comment: If you want to host a service on a dynamic IP address, you can use DynDNS service to associate your dynamic IP with a DNS name. Just want to add this option is working.